# Gstreamer pipeline stopped while playing only video from .mp4 file

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am working on gstreamer pipeline to get video from .mp4 file, during which encountered with below error.

**Pipeline used:**

**gst-launch filesrc location=/home/sample1/Holy.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux ! queue ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! v4l2sink**

**Error:**

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
** (gst-launch-0.10:3658): CRITICAL **: gst_v4l2sink_sync_rotation: assertion v4l2_ioctl (fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control) >= 0' failed

** (gst-launch-0.10:3658): CRITICAL **: gst_v4l2sink_sync_rotation: assertion `v4l2_ioctl (fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control) >= 0' failed

** (gst-launch-0.10:3658): CRITICAL **: gst_v4l2sink_sync_flip: assertion `v4l2_ioctl (fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &control) >= 0' failed
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:demux: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
Additional debug info:
qtdemux.c(3838): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:demux:
streaming stopped, reason error

ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...

!!!!!!!!!unreference all the remaining buffers!!!!!!!!!Freeing pipeline ...

This pipeline is executed on TI DM8148 board, where requirement is to use only software encoders (not OMX encoders).
Please guide me

1. whether it is possible to extract only video from .mp4 file ?
2. how to form gstreamer pipeline to get only video.

I have tried various possibilities, but could not get the right elements for the pipeline.

Any suggestions and solutions will be highly helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is
2. Your pipeline looks correct for this task.

The issues seem to come from v4l2sink. Is there any other sink you could use? If you, for example, instead of displaying the video, would reencode it and save to a file you would see that the result is a video only output.

So, you need to investigate if there is any other video sink that could be used or investigate what's wrong with v4l2sink in your platform.